# how to store different files that need to searched in ASP.NET MVC 4 website

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search, lucene.net

My requirement is like job sites where a user can upload a document(can be PDF,Text or word document) like Resume/CV. Then all these documents can be searched for a specific or a combination of keyword and they also have to be ranked based on those key words. I need to know which technology can be good from performance point of view when the number of files are huge and also there are good number of request for searching and indexing.

The website is built using SQL Server. So can I store those files in SQL Server? Will be good in terms of performance.

Or can it be done alone using Lucene.NET and i can store those files in single folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the best suggestion is to use Lucene ....

you can save your documents as they are with some unique path name/file_name , and use that as identifier when you index the documents ... I am sure you can find a lot of similar examples if you search Lucene ..